# Two activities one table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two  activities that I use to gather data for one sqlite table. What is the best way to do this. I assume I should have two classes possibly three one for each activity and maybe one for handling the database. I assume I should create an intent to call the second activity and I could pass a bundle using put extras on the intent to pass data and then update the database from the second activity after gathering all the information. Is it better to pass the context from the first activity and somehow parse the context from the second activity? I am confused about maintaining state from one activity to the next.

Comment: What's the data actually you are trying to manage?

Comment: You could try to use a Singleton which provides the Data and can change the data. So you are able to get data from all of your Activities

Comment: You could also use fragments instead of activities then you do not need to pass values between activities at all.

Comment: Use the concept of COntentProviders to solve your DB problem .

Comment: you can create a content provider and access the database through it , then you can access your db from whichever activity you want

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways like:

1) The best way is to use fragments so that you can keep gathering data and at the end you can store data. And it is always good practice to separate modules into different classes like in your for database operation.

2) And if you are thinking to pass bundle then you must use parceble for data consistency.

3) If your data is only string and you don't want to use fragments then it's okay to pass bundle.

4)Or you may use ContentProvider but its pretty hectic.

Good luck...